# What indoor plant will be able to absorb 0.5-1L of human urine daily?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, watering, plant-recommendations, greywater

I´ve recently moved into a place with a shared bathroom.  I enjoy my birthday suit when I´m at home, but suspect that others might not.  Hence my question.  I have no balcony, my window gets 2-3 hours of weak sunlight a day, my indoor temperature is ca. 20C, and I´m willing to get a growth light.  Is there a simple botanical solution to my predicament?

Answer (score 1):

None at all - human urine is a useful component on compost heaps, and if sprayed on grass, will likely make it grow thicker and greener - but only in limited in amounts,and never in contained plants. Too  much uric acid for  any plant in a pot, especially the amount and frequency you're talking about. Put some pants on and use the bathroom instead...

UPDATE

In response to your query re bicarbonate - its not just uric acid that's a problem. Your urine may contain pathogens, and certainly will have too much nitrogen for a plant on a daily basis, not to mention, with that quantity of fluid daily, any potted plant will be over 'watered'. Which I'm afraid still means the answer is 'none...'

Comment: I suspected pants would be the inevitable answer.  How about if I buffer it with bicarbonate?

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

[A study published in PubMed.gov](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18578152) concluded that "Generally the results showed that human urine compared well with urea as a source of N for crops but optimum rates depend on the sensitivity of the crops to soil salinity, which should be monitored where human urine is regularly used for fertilizing crops." There are many communities where urine is regularly and successfully used as fertilizer. Some modern communities have a horror of such use which may be unfounded, with the result that a lot of useful nutrient is flushed to the ocean. Out of sight, out of mind.

The problem is that it is too concentrated for immediate use raw. The body is doing the right thing, keeping as much water as it can while eliminating wastes; the concentrated form is useful since we can store it more easily if necessary. Gardeners are advised to dilute it 10 times to make it usable. So in your case you are looking at disposing of not one litre but 11 litres of fertilizer per day. That's enough to do a NY apartment building, if not an entire block.

Urine as fertilizer is particularly useful on marginal soils (for example soils with high proportion of sand) where nitrogen is rapidly flushed away by rains and needs to be replaced quickly. Those rains also help keep the accumulating soil salinity down.

If you are serious about avoiding flushing pollution to the oceans talk to a few gardeners and allotment holders; you may find someone who is willing to take your offering and use it as it was meant to be used. Save a few large containers and label them appropriately.

In sum, you could use it on a field of potatoes or squash, but there is no use for it in an apartment.